# Property not getting serialized in Json via newtonsoft

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

There are many properties defined in class but one of the property is not getting serialized(using newtonsoft) and that property is mentioned below:

```
public override string Value
{​​​​
  set    
  {
​​​​
    if (value == null)    
    {    ​​​​
       this.Null = true;    
    }​​ ​ ​
    else if (value == string.Empty)
    {    ​​​​
       _A = string.Empty;    
       _P = string.Empty;    
       _S = string.Empty;    
    }​​​ ​
    else
    {​​​ ​

         value = _A + _P + _S;    
     }​​​​

   }​​​​    
}
```

but when we define getter in the property then it is getting serialized so please suggest; we do not want to place the getter in the property.

Answer (score 0):

Set `[JsonProperty]` attribute to your property.
But overall, you could have your getter as `private` - so you'll not expose data to other classes, but it could help to solve your problem.

Comment: thanks for your time, but problem is that we can not change code; until we have a concrete reason so please let me know why we have to place the [jsonproperty] attribute because newtonsoft already cater that

Answer (score 0):

Well, to start, you have no Get how will json now to serialize it, perhaps make it a method looks funny to have only a set on a property. If you like to populate your fields just tell json to do that using annotations

```
[JsonProperty("_A")]
private string _A ;

[JsonProperty("_P")]
private string _P ;

[JsonProperty("_S")]
private string _S;

[JsonIgnore]
public override string Value
{​​​​
  set    
  {
​​​​
    if (value == null)    
    {    ​​​​
       this.Null = true;    
    }​​ ​ ​
    else if (value == string.Empty)
    {    ​​​​
       _A = string.Empty;    
       _P = string.Empty;    
       _S = string.Empty;    
    }​​​ ​
    else
    {​​​ ​

         value = _A + _P + _S;    
     }​​​​

   }​​​​    
}
```